# Facebook API - Page Ratings and Reviews with 'has_rating'=false

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

So I am trying to access the Reviews/ratings of a page. I succeed at getting data but it's not complete.

On the page in question there are also reviews withing 'X amount of stars'. These reviews are text only. In the API these aren't returned.

Requesting `GET > v2.5/me/ratings` returns:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "created_time": "N/A",
      "reviewer": {
        "name": "N/A",
        "id": "N/A"
      },
      "rating": 5,
      "review_text": "fantastic shop",
      "has_rating": true,
      "has_review": true
    },
    {
      "created_time": "N/A",
      "reviewer": {
        "name": "N/A",
        "id": "N/A"
      },
      "rating": 5,
      "has_rating": true,
      "has_review": false
    },
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "N/A",
      "after": "N/A"
    }
  }
}
```

So basicly, there are some reviews on the page which have `"has_rating": false` yet have an set `review_text`. But these are **NOT** returned.

How do I access these.

Comment: Docs don’t say anything about those being filtered out, or that they’d need to be specifically requested. I suggest you file a bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: @Cbroe I reported this as a bug like you suggested.